# Invoking a JavaScript function inside display column (Display Tag)

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, displaytag

I am trying to invoke a JS function within display column but for some reason the links are not showing up. Am I doing anything wrong in here?

```
<display:column title="# of E-Sign Documents" class="displayColumns" >
            <c:forEach items="${intgList}" var="list">
                <a href= "javascript:locateFunc('viewESignDetails', {'url':'<integration:urlAction actionName="/integration/viewDetailsIntegration"><integration:urlParam key="esignIdentifier" value="${list.esignId}"/></integration:urlAction>',
                    'agencyCode':'${list.agencyCode}',
                    'cretedDate':'${list.createdDate}'}>)"
                    <c:out value="${list.esignNumDocs}"/>
                </a>
            </c:forEach>
</display:column>
```

Comment: Perhaps the links are not showing up because `intgList` is empty?

Comment: Or perhaps because you generate bad HTML, since the `href` attribute ends at the `"` after `actionName=`.

Comment: intgList is not empty, because all other fields are showing up this is the only column where I am doing looping through.

Comment: In case of bad xml/html I should get an error but the app is running fine and if I do source view I can see the values too btu it is not just showing up on the column.

Comment: You don't get error in the browser console?

Comment: nops. As I said I can see the data listed when I do source view in the browser but for some reason that data is not showing upon the column.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out: This is how I did it. The links go to the requested page. This is with some additional fields but just look at the quotation placement.

```
<display:column title="# of E-Sign Documents" class="displayColumns" >
            <c:forEach items="${intgList}" var="list">
                <a id="eSignNumDocs" href= "javascript:locateFunc('viewESignDetails', {'url':'<integration:urlAction actionName="/integration/viewDetailsIntegration"><integration:urlParam key="esignIdentifier" value="${list.esignId}"/></integration:urlAction>',
                    'agencyCode':'${list.agencyCode}',
                    'policyNumber':'${list.policyNumber}',
                    'policyState':'${list.policyState}',
                    'esignIdentifier':'${list.esignId}',
                    'esignVendorIdentifier':'${list.esignVendorIdentifier}',
                    'lob':'${list.lob}',
                    'transId':'${list.transId}',
                    'customerName':'${list.insuredName}',
                    'customerPhone':'${list.custPhone}',
                    'customerEmail':'${list.custEmail}',
                    'cretedDate':'${list.createdDate}'});">
                    <c:out value="${list.esignNumDocs}"/>
                </a>
            </c:forEach>
        </display:column>
```